# What Defines Opponent Behaviour in 'Quick Battle'?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

When I play the 'quick battle' offline mode of Soul Calibur V, I get the impression that I'm fighting real player's characters being controlled by the game's AI, based on the character names, and costumes.  Some of these characters behave wildly different from one another, to the point that it almost feels like I'm fighting actual human players (impossible, as I don't have Xbox Live Gold). Some of these characters are much more 'skilled' than others, as well.

What defines the behaviour of someone's character in quick-play mode?  Does the game 'watch' them play, and then try to use the same combos the player used in their games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the Ai sets a difficulty and the characters you face are not other people's cumstomized characters its precreated characters made by the developers. Like the developer of Tekken has created his own character in there aswell which is useing Devel-Jin's moveset.

Difficulty however is set by the Ai you can see the difficulty by looking at the rank at the character your facing. Ofcourse the original characters have the best titels and the hardest difficulty.

However the hardest Ai becomes so futile to fight against cause it pretty much fights acordingly to your fighting style preventing you from doing almost anything, you can never win by the same move cause the Ai knows what to do to counter, so basicly the Ai is set by your previous fights, not others.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support your last paragraph? In my experience, they're just regular (difficult) AI opponents.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the computer copies players from elsewhere. Maybe the A.I. is varied to the point that it imitates varying types of players.